# Implement UIVibrancyEffect in UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm surprised I can't find any discussion on this. I have a `UITableView` which I present in a `UIPopoverController`. The popover obviously has the standard blur effect as a background. (The table and its cells have no background so you can see right through)

I'd like to apply the `UIVibrancyEffect` as .separatorEffect to my `UITableView` but you can only create a vibrancy effect with a reference to a blur effect. I can't find any (safe and public) way to access the `UIPopoverController`'s blur effect to do this.

Surely there's a way?

Comment: Supply a value for the `popoverBackgroundViewClass`. Now you are in completely charge of the popover background view, so that means you are in charge of how it blurs what's behind it. Now it's _your_ blur effect.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to use the blur effect provided by the popover. You can create any blur effect you wish and use that to create the separator effect.

This should do the trick:

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark) //or .Light or .ExtraLight
self.tableView.separatorEffect = UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: blurEffect)
```